# Full command line as it was typed

Tags: python, command-line

I want to get the full command line as it was typed.

This:

`" ".join(sys.argv[:])`

doesn't work here (deletes double quotes). Also I prefer not to rejoin something that was parsed and split.

Any ideas?

Comment: @S.Lott that is not what -1's are intended for. Quoting the [help page on downvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down):

"Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."

Now if you think the OP expended no effort on the question, that's a different matter altogether. But in my understanding, downvotes are not intended to target ignorance.

Comment: Rejoining the argv[:] list isn't so bad if you use the right tool:  `shlex.join(sys.argv[:])` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.join).  It may not be exactly the same sting that was typed, but it ought to be equivalent.

Answer (score 32):

You're too late. By the time that the typed command gets to Python your shell has already worked its magic. For example, quotes get consumed (as you've noticed), variables get interpolated, etc.

Comment: Quotes are not consumed by Windows' CMD.

Answer (score 14):

In a Unix environment, this is not generally possible...the best you can hope for is the command line as passed to your process.

Because the shell (essentially *any* shell) may munge the typed command line in several ways before handing it to the OS for execution.

Answer (score 14):

### *nix

Look at [the initial stack layout (Linux on i386) that provides access to command line and environment of a program](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html#st): the process sees only separate arguments.

You can't get the command-line *as it was typed* in the general case. On Unix, the shell parses the command-line into separate arguments and eventually [`execv(path, argv)` function that invokes the corresponding syscall](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) is called. `sys.argv` is derived from `argv` parameter passed to the `execve()` function. You could get something equivalent using `" ".join(map(shlex.quote, sys.argv))` though you shouldn't need to e.g., if you want to restart the script with slightly different command-line parameters then `sys.argv` is enough ([in many cases](http://bugs.python.org/issue29857)), see [Is it possible to set the python -O (optimize) flag within a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7527983/4279)

There are some creative (non-practical) solutions:

- attach the shell using gdb and interrogate it (most shells are capable of repeating the same command twice)—you should be able to get almost the same command as it was typed—  or read its history file directly if it is updated before your process exits
- use screen, script utilities to get the terminal session
- use a keylogger, to get what was typed.

### Windows

On Windows the native `CreateProcess()` interface is a string but python.exe still receives arguments as a list. `subprocess.list2cmdline(sys.argv)` might help to reverse the process.  `list2cmdline` is designed for applications using [the same
rules as the MS C runtime](http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINCRULESCHANGE)—`python.exe` is one of them. `list2cmdline` doesn't return the command-line *as it was typed* but it returns a functional equivalent in this case.

On Python 2, you might need [`GetCommandLineW()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/846931/4279), to get Unicode characters from the command line that can't be represented in Windows ANSI codepage (such as cp1252).

Comment: It is OK for practical proposes. But, if you want to get all double space or tabs, this will not work (This is just a good "reconstruction" of the command line, not the original).

Comment: Usage is with one parameter. That means `subprocess.list2cmdline(sys.argv)` should be used.

Comment: @A.Sommerh: 1- It works for double space and tabs. It is what `subprocess` module uses to create a new process on Windows. Each command on Windows parses its own command-line. python.exe uses the same rules as `subprocess.list2cmdline()`. 2- I've approved your edit. It makes my mentioning the name of the function into a complete code example. I didn't mean to imply that `subprocess.list2cmdline()` is an actual call—the name suggest that you should pass a list and it returns a command line (as a string).

Comment: @J-F-Sebastian, I meant: "if you want to get all double spaces or tabs **of the original command line**, `subprocess.list2cmdline()` will not work as expected, _because some of them are lost when python construct_ `sys.argv`". Good edition of your answer by the way!

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, this probably cannot be done, at least not reliably.  In a few cases, you might be able to find a history file for the shell (e.g. - "bash", but not "tcsh") and get the user's typing from that.  I don't know how much, if any, control you have over the user's environment.

Comment: Even in the .history, some processing has been applied (! substitution at a minimum...). +1 for cleverness, though. Nice thought.

Comment: I believe that Bash, be default, doesn't write to the .history file except at the end of a session, so this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux there is `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` that is in the format of `argv[]` (i.e. there is 0x00 between all the lines and you can't really know how many strings there are since you don't get the argc; though you will know it when the file runs out of data ;).

You can be sure that that commandline is already munged too since all escaping/variable filling is done and parameters are nicely packaged (no extra spaces between parameters, etc.).

Comment: `cmdline` doesn't provide much in addition to `sys.argv`.

Comment: Thanks. This saved my bacon when I wanted to inspect the command line in a `.pth` triggered script which runs before the (`-m` specified) module has been loaded (or found).

Comment: Use `/proc/self/cmdline` so you don't have to get the pid

Answer (score 2):

You can use `psutil` that provides a **cross platform** solution:

```
import psutil
import os
my_process = psutil.Process( os.getpid() )
print( my_process.cmdline() )
```

If that's not what you're after you can go further and get the command line of the parent program(s):

```
my_parent_process = psutil.Process( my_process.ppid() )
print( my_parent_process.cmdline() )
```

The variables will still be split into its components, but unlike `sys.argv` they won't have been modified by the interpreter.

Comment: psutil does not exist here. Doesn't seem like an easy solution. (Windows 10, Python 3)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, I'd suggest monkeying with the `~/.bash_history` file or the shell `history` command, although I believe the command must finish executing before it's added to the shell history.

I started playing with:

```
import popen2
x,y = popen2.popen4("tail ~/.bash_history")
print x.readlines()
```

But I'm getting weird behavior where the shell doesn't seem to be completely flushing to the `.bash_history` file.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you can do it from within the Python program to get back the full command string. Since the command-line arguments are already handled once before it's sent into `sys.argv`, this is how you can reconstruct that string.

```
commandstring = '';

for arg in sys.argv:
    if ' ' in arg:
        commandstring += '"{}"  '.format(arg);
    else:
        commandstring+="{}  ".format(arg);

print(commandstring);
```

Example:

Invoking like this from the terminal,

```
./saferm.py sdkf lsadkf -r sdf -f sdf -fs -s "flksjfksdkfj sdfsdaflkasdf"
```

will give the same string in commandstring:

```
./saferm.py sdkf lsadkf -r sdf -f sdf -fs -s "flksjfksdkfj sdfsdaflkasdf"
```

Comment: `./something '$(rm -rf ~)'` is very, **very** different from `./something "$(rm -rf ~)"`.

Comment: Similarly, `something 'foo "bar" baz'` is different from `something "foo" "bar" baz"`

Comment: `' '.join(pipes.quote(x) for x in sys.argv)` would be a safer alternative.

Comment: `shlex.quote` rather than `pipes.quote` for the Py3 compatible version.

Answer (score -1):

I needed to replay a complex command line with multi-line arguments and values that look like options but which are not.

Combining an answer from [2009](https://stackoverflow.com/a/667754/9201239) and various comments, here is a modern python 3 version that works quite well on unix.

```
import sys
import shlex
print(sys.executable, " ".join(map(shlex.quote, sys.argv)))
```

Let's test:

```
$ cat << EOT > test.py
import sys
import shlex
print(sys.executable, " ".join(map(shlex.quote, sys.argv)))
EOT
```

then:

```
$ python test.py --foo 1 --bar " aha " --tar 'multi \
line arg' --nar '--prefix1 --prefix2'
```

prints:

```
/usr/bin/python test.py --foo 1 --bar ' aha ' --tar 'multi \
line arg' --nar '--prefix1 --prefix2'
```

Note that it got `'--prefix1 --prefix2'` quoted correctly and the multi-line argument too!

The only difference is the full python path.

That was all I needed.

Thank you for the ideas to make this work.

---

Update: here is a more advanced version of the same that replays desired env vars and also wraps the long output nicely with bash line breaks so that the output can be immediately pasted in forums and not needing to manually deal with breaking up long lines to avoid horizontal scrolling.

```
import os
import shlex
import sys
def get_orig_cmd(max_width=80, full_python_path=False):
    """
    Return the original command line string that can be replayed 
    nicely and wrapped for 80 char width
    Args:
        - max_width: the width to wrap for. defaults to 80
        - full_python_path: whether to replicate the full path 
          or just the last part (i.e. `python`). default to `False`
    """

    cmd = []

    # deal with critical env vars
    env_keys = ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]
    for key in env_keys:
        val = os.environ.get(key, None)
        if val is not None:
            cmd.append(f"{key}={val}")

    # python executable (not always needed if the script is executable)
    python = sys.executable if full_python_path else sys.executable.split("/")[-1]
    cmd.append(python)

    # now the normal args
    cmd += list(map(shlex.quote, sys.argv))

    # split up into up to MAX_WIDTH lines with shell multi-line escapes
    lines = []
    current_line = ""
    while len(cmd) > 0:
        current_line += f"{cmd.pop(0)} "
        if len(cmd) == 0 or len(current_line) + len(cmd[0]) + 1 > max_width - 1:
            lines.append(current_line)
            current_line = ""
    return "\\\n".join(lines)

print(get_orig_cmd())
```

Here is an example that this function produced:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python ./scripts/benchmark/trainer-benchmark.py \
--base-cmd \
' examples/pytorch/translation/run_translation.py --model_name_or_path t5-small \
--output_dir output_dir --do_train --label_smoothing 0.1 --logging_strategy no \
--save_strategy no --per_device_train_batch_size 32 --max_source_length 512 \
--max_target_length 512 --num_train_epochs 1 --overwrite_output_dir \
--source_lang en --target_lang ro --dataset_name wmt16 --dataset_config "ro-en" \
--source_prefix "translate English to Romanian: " --warmup_steps 50 \
--max_train_samples 2001 --dataloader_num_workers 2 ' \
--target-metric-key train_samples_per_second --repeat-times 1 --variations \
'|--fp16|--bf16' '|--tf32' --report-metric-keys 'train_loss train_samples' \
--table-format console --repeat-times 2 --base-variation ''
```

Note, that it's super complex as one argument has multiple arguments as its value and it is multiline too.

Also note that this particular version doesn't rewrap single arguments - if any are longer than the requested width they remain unwrapped (by design).