# How to retrieve user input BEFORE arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, command-line-arguments

As explained in [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4033723/13815479), I understand how to retrieve arguments entered by user over powershell. However, I am interested in getting whatever was exactly typed before arguments. For example, for the command entered by user: `py myscript.py`, I should print/retrieve `py`.

Similarly for user input `python myscript.py`, I should print/get `python` ?

Comment: I think you want `sys.executable`

Comment: Tried that, it prints `/path/to/Python37-32/python.exe` or `/path/to/Python38-32/python.exe` when I use `python` and `py` in command line, respectively. But that still doesn't tell whether the user entered `python` or `py`?

Comment: You might check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667540/full-command-line-as-it-was-typed Though it does not really look hopeful.